# @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self)?

Tags: ios, swiftui, appdelegate, property-wrapper

When using SwiftUI's @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor, many in the Swift community(SO, blogs, courses) register the app delegate class like this:

```
@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
```

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiapplicationdelegateadaptor) uses code similar to this example:

```
@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor var appDelegate: AppDelegate
```

I've been using the latter with no problems that I've noticed. The latter seems more readable. Could someone explain the difference and when I should use one over the other? I think I'm not understanding something.

Comment: Probably it's just type inferring. It doesn't matter where you specify the type because it's supposed to be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fully specified version would be:

```
@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate: AppDelegate
```

Since both types (variable type and propertyWrapper type) are the same, you can omit either of them and it will be inferred.